# Set column color in google chart

Tags: javascript, colors, charts, google-visualization

I am using google charts to build a line chart. I am using a Category Filter to toggle what columns are displayed like is shown in the fiddle below.

http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/WaUu2/

How can you set colors for each column so that they will always have that color. For example if you remove the column Foo in the fiddle example, the column Bar will get its color.

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['controls']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Year');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Foo');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Bar');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Baz');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Cad');
    data.addRows([
        ['2005',  45, 60, 89, 100],
        ['2006',  155, 50, 79, 24],
        ['2007',  35, 31, 140, 53],
        ['2008',  105, 23, 43, 82],
        ['2009',  120, 56, 21, 67],
        ['2010',  65, 19, 34, 134],
        ['2011',  80, 23, 130, 40],
        ['2012',  70, 140, 83, 90]
    ]);

    var columnsTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    columnsTable.addColumn('number', 'colIndex');
    columnsTable.addColumn('string', 'colLabel');
    var initState= {selectedValues: []};
    // put the columns into this data table (skip column 0)
    for (var i = 1; i < data.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
        columnsTable.addRow([i, data.getColumnLabel(i)]);
        // you can comment out this next line if you want to have a default selection other than the whole list
        initState.selectedValues.push(data.getColumnLabel(i));
    }
    // you can set individual columns to be the default columns (instead of populating via the loop above) like this:
    // initState.selectedValues.push(data.getColumnLabel(4));

    var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        chartType: 'BarChart',
        containerId: 'chart_div',
        dataTable: data,
        options: {
            title: 'Foobar',
            width: 600,
            height: 400
        }
    });

    var columnFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        controlType: 'CategoryFilter',
        containerId: 'colFilter_div',
        dataTable: columnsTable,
        options: {
            filterColumnLabel: 'colLabel',
            ui: {
                label: 'Columns',
                allowTyping: false,
                allowMultiple: true,
                allowNone: false,
                selectedValuesLayout: 'belowStacked'
            }
        },
        state: initState
    });

    function setChartView () {
        var state = columnFilter.getState();
        var row;
        var view = {
            columns: [0]
        };
        for (var i = 0; i < state.selectedValues.length; i++) {
            row = columnsTable.getFilteredRows([{column: 1, value: state.selectedValues[i]}])[0];
            view.columns.push(columnsTable.getValue(row, 0));
        }
        // sort the indices into their original order
        view.columns.sort(function (a, b) {
            return (a - b);
        });
        chart.setView(view);
        chart.draw();
    }
    google.visualization.events.addListener(columnFilter, 'statechange', setChartView);

    setChartView();
    columnFilter.draw();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var colors=["#3366cc","#dc3912","#ff9900","#109618","#990099","#0099c6","#dd4477","#66aa00","#b82e2e","#316395","#994499","#22aa99","#aaaa11","#6633cc","#e67300","#8b0707","#651067","#329262","#5574a6","#3b3eac","#b77322","#16d620","#b91383","#f4359e","#9c5935","#a9c413","#2a778d","#668d1c","#bea413","#0c5922","#743411"];

    //the code
    view.columns.sort(function (a, b) {
        return (a - b);
    });
    chart.getOptions().series=[];
    for(var i=1;i<view.columns.length;i++){
        chart.getOptions().series.push({color:colors[view.columns[i]-1]});
    }
    //the code
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/juvian/WaUu2/236/

Comment: Could you explain this a little better? I'm trying to use this solution to keep series types the same in a combo chart. I have one 'line' type that I would like to keep with the column as the columns are selected and deselected. The problem is I don't understand quite what is going on. Thanks! Could I do var types = [bar, bar, bar, bar, bar, bar, bar, line] and use the same solution?

Comment: @Jglstewart not sure if I understood, do you have a fiddle? This code is for setting different colors to each series, keeping the same colors even when some columns are deselected. How exaclty are you setting the types?

Comment: @juvian see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28090882/google-charts-how-to-get-index-from-label

Comment: @juvian, does the snippet works for Google Column Chart ? I have a similar issue where I need to set colors for each stack column.

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy should work for bar and column chart yeah, just have to change the loop I think

Comment: It would be great if you could add some snippet.

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy quite busy till thursday, but leave me a fiddle and I can try ;)

Comment: @juvian a sample reference - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32881560/google-visualization-change-haxis-and-vaxis-values-and-show-fix-chart-sections