# Google Charts: How to keep options the same with dynamic combo chart

Tags: google-visualization

I've used the following code http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/WaUu2/ which allows me to toggle on and off series from my combo chart. The issue I was having with it, is my combo chart used both line and bar series types. When I toggled series from the chart on and off I would lose my series type setting. I put together the following to keep my average column as a line chart and the rest as a bar chart.

```js
function setChartView() {
    var state = columnFilter.getState();
    var row;
    var view = {
        columns: [0],
    };
    var labels = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < state.selectedValues.length; i++) {
        row = columnsTable.getFilteredRows([{
            column: 1,
            value: state.selectedValues[i]
        }])[0];
        view.columns.push(columnsTable.getValue(row, 0));
        labels.push([columnsTable.getValue(row, 0), columnsTable.getValue(row, 1)]);
    }
    // sort the indices into their original order
    labels.sort(function(a, b) {
        return (a[0] - b[0]);
    });
    view.columns.sort(function(a, b) {
        return (a - b);
    });

    chart.setView(view);

    for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
        chart.setOption('series.' + i + '.type', 'bars');
        if (labels[i][1] == 'Average') {
            chart.getOptions().series[i].type = 'line';
        }
    }

    chart.draw();
}

google.visualization.events.addListener(columnFilter, 'statechange', setChartView);

setChartView();
columnFilter.draw();
```

It appears to be working for my specific case, however, what if I wanted to keep all of my options the same?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
                  for(var i = 0; i < view.columns.length; i++){
                        var col = view.columns[i]
                        chart.setOption('series.' + col + '.type', 'bars');
                        if(col == yourAverageColumnOriginalIndex){
                            chart.getOptions().series[col].type = 'line';
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I've tried messing around with it a bit to get it to carry all options with it, but I couldn't figure it out. I know you've figured out a way to carry the colours with the series, so I thought maybe you'd have a better solution to keep all options.

Comment: Problem is your label index is not the same as column index. Do you have a fiddle with an example of your code an data?

Comment: I sorted them using :  labels.sort(function(a, b) {
        return (a[0] - b[0]);
    });
    view.columns.sort(function(a, b) {
        return (a - b);

Comment: I don't have fiddle. but I'll get it.

Comment: Data seems to be working alright, you want to keep same colors?

Comment: Yeah, this works, but it only works for this exact situation. Say I had more options for series, including color, type, ect.. How do I keep them all?

Comment: @Jglstewart Was super hard to understand how the view works, but after a lot of trial and error I believe this is working: http://jsfiddle.net/juvian/thu1895e/3/

Comment: Thanks! Correct me if i'm wrong, but I think this only works for color the specific case that type is line for column 5. What i'm looking for is something that keeps ALL options pertaining to the series.

Comment: @Jglstewart what I did keeps color and keeps the average line as a line, which is not always in column 5. In theory it should keep other options as well, haven´t tried it though. But works for line type and color

Comment: Okay, I'm looking for something that keeps all settings no matter what they are for each series. Your code only works for specifics. Imagine, I didn't know what the settings were going to be, and I had to keep them paired with each series of data.